# How to login to reddit.com using the api?

Tags: html, api, post, reddit

I'm not sure how to format my request url to login to reddit using the api. I've tried this but I just get a page not found error

```
https://ssl.reddit.com/api/login/?user=myusername&passwd=mypassword&api_type=json
```

Comment: How are you `post`ing this? Where's the rest of your code? You're not just pasting this in to your browser's address bar...right?

Comment: Well that is how I am testing it... I am expecting to get back some json as a response.

Comment: But it's a `POST` request — you need to `POST` to that url. `GET` vars—which you're using—won't work here.

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded cocoa-rest-client to test this.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116825/i-am-unable-to-use-reddits-apis-to-log-in). User [Strelok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2788/strelok) has a great answer

```
public void someTest() throws IOException
    {
        URL u = new URL( "https://ssl.reddit.com/api/login/myusername" );
        login( u, "myusername", "mypassword" );
    }

    public static void login( URL url, String user, String pw ) throws IOException
    {

        String data = "api_type=json&user=" + user + "&passwd=" + pw;
        HttpURLConnection ycConnection = null;
        ycConnection = ( HttpURLConnection ) url.openConnection();
        ycConnection.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
        ycConnection.setDoOutput( true );
        ycConnection.setUseCaches( false );
        ycConnection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type",
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" );
        ycConnection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", String.valueOf( data.length() ) );

        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
            ycConnection.getOutputStream() );
        wr.writeBytes( data );
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
        InputStream is = ycConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( is ) );
        String line;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while ( ( line = rd.readLine() ) != null )
        {
            response.append( line );
            response.append( '\r' );
        }
        for ( Entry< String, List< String >> r : ycConnection.getHeaderFields().entrySet() )
        {
            System.out.println( r.getKey() + ": " + r.getValue() );
        }
        rd.close();
        System.out.println( response.toString() );
    }
```