# 403 Forbidden: get upvoted comments from reddit

Tags: java, api, reddit

I am working on reddit api to get comments, upvoted, downvoted etc. When I hit " https://www.reddit.com/user/{username}/comments.json", it is working properly. When I hit " https://www.reddit.com/user/{username}/upvoted.json" it gives me **403 Forbidden**. I added access_token also but same error. 
How can I get the second url working?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the access control policies of a web site.

Answer (score 3):

The user has deselected `make my votes public` in his preferences and thus you get this error.

**Note:**
If you directly get this URL with java you are not logged in, so even if it is your account you won't be able to access it.
You might want to refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116825/i-am-unable-to-use-reddits-apis-to-log-in) for trying to log in.